# How do I get the normal domain from an inequality condition (application of Fubini's Theorem)?

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems, iterated-integrals

I want to compute the volume of the 3-dimensional unit ball.

$A := \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$

From this I want to get the normal domain as:

$A = \{(x,y,z): x \in [-1,1], y \in [-\sqrt{1-x^2}, \sqrt{1-x^2}], z \in [-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}]\}$

The question is, how do I get the x, y, z intervals from the inequality?

The more concrete (but less 'exact') question is: Is it ok to 'leave out' z in the definition of the y interval, i. e. disregard z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer (any corrections or improvements appreciated):

$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1
$$

Because $x^2 \geq 0$, $y^2 \geq 0$, $z^2 \geq 0$:

$$
0 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1
$$

From that we can say, because $z^2 \geq 0$ and $0 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$ that leaving out $z$ will not change the in equality and get

$$
0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1
$$

From this we can split off

$$
x^2 + y^2 \leq 1
$$

which can be changed to express $y$ with $x$.

The same holds for expressing $z$ with $x$ and $y$.